# Do I have to explicitly support the Wow6432Node in ADMX-files?

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, registry, group-policy

We're providing an ADMX-file with our (32bit) application so it can be centrally configured via group policies. Do I have to explicitly provide policies for the Wow6432Node registry keys in case the app is installed on a 64bit client OS or does the policy system handle this itself?

The ADMX-file currently provides both Preferences (i.e. values under `[HKLM/HKCU]\Software\Company\Product`) and "fully-managed" Policies (i.e. for `[HKLM/HKCU]\Software\Policies\Company\Product`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ***policies*** the answer is no (i.e. no Wow6432 node).
For ***preferences*** the answer is - "it depends".

I will explain the difference. Some keys in registry are redirected into Wow6432 node for 32-bit applications, some others are not. The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) lists shared and redirected keys. [HKLM/HKCU]\Software\Policies key (and everything underneath) is expluded from redirection, it is the same for both 64 and 32 bit processes. This means that for policies you only need to provide one key.

Unlike Software\Policies key, Software\ *is* redirected. The keys you need would  depend on bitness of your product. If you only install 64 bit version of your app on 64 bit OS, you can configure one, if you support 32 bit app running on 64 bit OS, you need two.